# Shadow dom hides innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

when creating a custom element with shadow dom, and setting the element's innerHTML it isn't displayed. Why? and is there away to way to prevent this from happening?

//JS Code

```
export default class VideoPlayer extends DomElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
      const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(mountPoint);
  }
}
window.customElements.define('video-player', VideoPlayer);
```

//HTML CODE

```
<video-player>Why is this text hidden?</video-player>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why? It's one of the main features of a Shadow DOM: to **mask/recover** the initial DOM called *light DOM* with a new DOM called the *Shadow DOM*.

Read more on Google's [introduction to Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom).

To prevent this from happening:

- Don't use Shadow DOM if you don't need them. You can create Custom Elements without Shadow DOM.
- Use [`<slot>`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#slots) to insert parts of all of the light DOM into the Shadow DOM:

```js
class VideoPlayer extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
          .innerHTML = '<slot></slot>'
  }
}
window.customElements.define('video-player', VideoPlayer);
```

```html
<video-player>Why is this text hidden?</video-player>
```